# Generate config from existing infrastructure

Tags: terraform

I read on the website that this feature will be available in a future release. 
I"ve been digging through the issues and prs on github but I cannot find anything related.

Has it been road mapped?

Comment: This isn't something that can be answered here. You mention that you've read through issues and that's going to be the best place to get this information.

Comment: They should be asking for this as a feature request issue on GitHub or more likely subscribing to the existing issue there.